# event to track ckEditor Color Button , color click

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x, django-ckeditor

What I am trying to achieve is that update Ckediter color button plugin toolbar drop-down/Icon bg color on the base of the color selected by the user on click.

let say I want to display a alert message on click of any color from the color button popup

[image]

Have also referred to the unanswered link like following

[How to know which button is clicked](https://ckeditor.com/old//forums/CKEditor-3.x/How-know-which-button-clicked)

I have tried the following code, to call using color button a tag class  "cke_colorbox" .But it is also not working.

```
$('.cke_colorbox').click(function () {
  alert('Color Selected');
 });
```

FYI: I am using multiple and dynamic ckeditoer text area on a page.

Comment: So basically you wanted to know, which button is clicked?

Comment: Yes, Right. so of base of the same, I can do respective action.

Comment: I added an answer and hope this is the base idea you are looking for

Comment: Sorry, but not working for ckEditoer color button toolbar.

Comment: can you give an url of ckEditoer ? or do you have the html content of that toolbar?

Comment: https://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/colorbutton.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165277/discussion-between-bj-patel-and-silentcoder).

Answer (score 0):

This is a guidance to your question as an answer. Think your toolbar has set for buttons and you wanted to know which button is clicked and depend on that you want perform some action. Refer below code to get an idea,

```js
$('#toolbar>li').click(function () {
    var buttonIndex =  $("#toolbar>li").index($(this));
    alert(buttonIndex);
    //Perform action for the button
    //switch(buttonIndex){
    //case 0: break;
    //default:break;
    //}
     
     
});
```

```css
#toolbar>li{
display:inline-block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="toolbar">
<li><button>A</button></li>
<li><button>B</button></li>
<li><button>C</button></li>
<li><button>D</button></li>
<li><button>E</button></li>
<li><button>F</button></li>
</ul>
```